# MVC4 AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have in my routeconfig route:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Login", url: "login", defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });
```

It works fine except when the user is not authorized and calls a function with [Authorize] he is redirected to account/login, but not to /login as it should.
Can you give me please an idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url of login page you set in web.config:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

You should change it here. 
RouteTable is about mapping of incoming urls to controllers and actions.

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much! forgot about this setting...